# How to open and close dropdown on btn-click, but in same time with outside click close?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have dropdown which is open on btn click.

```
  toggleAllCategories() {
    this.setState({ isOpenAllCategories: !this.state.isOpenAllCategories });
  }
```

Also on outside click dropdown is closed.

```
  handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.toggleAllCategories();
    }
  }
```

But problem is cus I can't open and close dropdown by clicking on button.

When I click two times on the button dropdown is still open, cus of outside click implementation.

How to make togglebleDroopdown on button and close on outside click in same time?

**STACKBLITZ live example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-coihzv?file=index.js

This is component and whole implementation of dropdown and entire related logic:

```
class AllCategories extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      allCategories: getAllCategoriesList(),
      isOpenAllCategories: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside.bind(this));
  }

  setWrapperRef(node) {
    this.wrapperRef = node;
  }

  handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.toggleAllCategories();
    }
  }

  toggleAllCategories() {
    this.setState({ isOpenAllCategories: !this.state.isOpenAllCategories });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <AllCategoriesButton toggleAllCategories={this.toggleAllCategories} />

        {this.state.isOpenAllCategories ? (
          <div className="all-categories-wrapper" ref={(node) => this.setWrapperRef(node)}>
            <div className="all-categories">
              <ul className="all-categories-list">
                <li className="all-categories-list-item">All Categories</li>
                {this.state.allCategories.map((category) => (
                  <li
                    className={`all-categories-list-item ${
                      category.selected ? 'all-categories-list-item-active' : ''
                    }`}
                  >
                    {category.name}
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ''
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the element in which the click was triggered using `event.target.tagName`.

So to prevent toggling twice you can do the following:

```
 handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target) &&event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'button') {
      this.toggleAllCategories();
    }
  }
```

---

EDIT: 
**Another Approach**

- Create a ref for the button lets name it `buttonRef`.

Now update the `handleClickOutside` to this:

```
handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target) &&event.target !== buttonRef.current) {
      this.toggleAllCategories();
    }
  }
```

This will be more appropriate way.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: This means if click happed on button area don't trigger close outside?

Comment: Can I check trough event class of clicked tag, and than handle that by class of button instead of button tag?

Comment: Right, if you click on the same button again you dont want to trigger the outside click. I am updating my answeer with another approach. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In case of button click `toggleAllCategories` is triggered twice. One from the click of the button and another from `handleClickOutside` .you need to call it from one place

Comment: Yes, cus I need to be able to close Dropdown on Outside click and on button click.