# Detect click outside multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to detect a click outside a set of components. I have multiple components called `Block`, inside an `Artboard` component. Inside each `Block` component, this is what I have as of now:

```js
const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
  if (ref && !ref.contains(e.target)) {
    setSelected(false);
  }
}
```

So this works, but whenever I want to actually click on a block and select it, `handleClickOutside()` actually fires because I'm clicking outside every other block component.

```
 -------
|       |
|       |
|       |
 -------

^ This is a selected block

When I click outside of it, it will be deselected.

 -------
|       |
|       |
|       |
 -------

^ But when I click on this block, I'm also clicking
outside the beforementioned block, which causes the
handleClickOutside function to fire.
```

I simply want to be able to select a component, then deselect it by clicking outside of it, without affecting other block components.

Comment: Hey did the answer work for you? Or did you got another workaround ?

Comment: Can you provide a full coding example?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this but I have tried this on Codesandbox. And it works for the use case you define.

So in `onClick` handler of the `Box` component you call `preventDefault` and in the handler `handleClickOutside` you check whether `e.defaultPrevented` is `true`.

Here is the Codesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-wind-tr1ns

---

Also if you can accommodate to use `ref` for the `Box` component. You can read this answer: [How to open and close dropdown on btn-click, but in same time with outside click close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304918/how-to-open-and-close-dropdown-on-btn-click-but-in-same-time-with-outside-click/57305105#57305105)

Hope this helps!

Looking for a better answer as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

There are a few simpler approaches than the one with multiple refs and state variables:

1. One where `className` of DOM elements decides whether to select or deselect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const WrapperComponent = ({ items }) => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
  const componentRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (componentRef.current) {
        if (!componentRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
          setSelectedItem(null); //Is click outside our wrapperDiv
        } else if (event.target.className === 'wrapperDiv') {
          setSelectedItem(null); //Is click directly on our wrapperDiv
        }
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleItemClick = (item) => {
    setSelectedItem(item);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={componentRef} className="wrapperDiv">
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            cursor: 'pointer',
            background: selectedItem === item ? 'red' : 'blue',
            margin: '20px',
          }}
          onClick={(event) => {
            handleItemClick(item);
          }}
        >
          {item}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

// Example usage:
const App = () => {
  const items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

  return (
    <div>
      <WrapperComponent items={items} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here we know what class we want to really listen to clicks on, and based on that we are changing state. A `ref` is still kept for the wrapper component. The logic just check if current item clicked is outside the wrapper div or if it is the wrapper div itself. In both cases the selection is made to null.

2. One where we prevent the [`event bubbling`](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const WrapperComponent = ({ items }) => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
  const componentRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (componentRef.current) {
        setSelectedItem(null);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleItemClick = (item) => {
    setSelectedItem(item);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={componentRef}>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            cursor: 'pointer',
            background: selectedItem === item ? 'red' : 'blue',
            margin: '20px',
          }}
          onClick={(event) => {
            event.stopPropagation();
            handleItemClick(item);
          }}
        >
          {item}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

// Example usage:
const App = () => {
  const items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

  return (
    <div>
      <WrapperComponent items={items} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is a [doc](https://blog.logrocket.com/event-bubbling-capturing-react/#using-event-stop-propagation-react) explaining the whole thing, but the gist is that we are not allowing events to go up from child components to parent.

I do not recommend to use this blindly as it can lead to all ancsetor event listeners to stop working and this can be a problem based on what we want.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-sgmrnu?file=src%2FApp.jsx&terminal=dev)

Comment: I'm using Preact instead of React. My import map is instead `import { createRef } from "preact"; import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "preact/hooks"; import { forwardRef } from 'preact/compat';` It runs fine, but if there is a selected red block and I click on itself or another, then it will add an outside click (all `false`s), unlike the demo. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Not sure. Haven't worked on preact. You can use some other logic in that case. Maybe use a className based approach. For every click check if className is matching with anyone of your items. Do not rely on click of the `Block` component (not the best way tbh). Maybe share some codesandbox so we can help

Comment: Here is a className based approach: much refined than earlier since my working hours are over :D https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-sgmrnu?file=src%2FApp.jsx&terminal=dev @Ooker

Comment: you rocks :D. That's definitely simpler. If you make that an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Updated the answer, to include both approaches around className and bubbling. Removed the old answer as it was more noise and could lead to time waste for others

Comment: How about making it unselected when it's out focused? Sometimes you don't use mouse to click but use keyboard to navigate

Answer (score 0):

When multiple `onClick` event handlers are associated with the same HTML element, each handler will be invoked when the element is clicked. If you want to prevent the event from bubbling up to parent elements and triggering their click event handlers, you can use `event.stopPropagation()`.

```js
const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  if (ref && !ref.contains(e.target)) {
    setSelected(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: where to put that `handleClickOutside`? The blocks? My code for block 1: `<div> ref={ref1} onClick={(event) => {handleClickOutside(event)}}</div>`. The same for block 2. It doesn't work